# Scala object Action in package mvc is deprecated

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm currently working on a new project and face a warning I haven't seen in older projects yet.

[image]

The warning says that `Action` from the `mvc` package is deprecated since 2.6.0. I guess it has something to do with Play or Scala itself. So this is my code responsible for the warning:

```
def getLists: Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {
    listRepo.getLists.map(lists => Ok(Json.obj("lists" -> lists)))
}
```

My `buildt.sbt` looks like this:

[image]

And this is how I import the `Action` object:

```
import play.api.mvc.{Action, AnyContent, Controller}
```

Is there an equivalent alternative or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The warning message tells you what to do (more information is in the linked sections of the Play 2.6 migration guide):

1. [`Inject an ActionBuilder (e.g. DefaultActionBuilder)`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26#scala-actionbuilder-and-bodyparser-changes) or
2. [`extend BaseController/AbstractController/InjectedController`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26#scala-controller-changes)